# Plotting 3d network in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, graph, three.js, webgl

I am trying to generate a 3d graph using three.js

Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.119.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; }
      canvas { display: block; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
      document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

      var node1_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
      var node1_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
      var node1 = new THREE.Mesh( node1_geometry, node1_material );
      node1.position.set(-2, 4, 1);

      var node2_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
      var node2_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
      var node2 = new THREE.Mesh( node2_geometry, node2_material );
      node2.position.set(2, 4, 1);

      var edge_geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
      edge_geometry.vertices.push( node1.position, node2.position );
      var edge_material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, linewidth: 2 } );
      var edge = new THREE.Line( edge_geometry, edge_material );

      scene.add( node1 );
      scene.add( node2 );
      scene.add( edge );

      camera.position.z = 5;

      var animate = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
      };

      animate();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But this only gives a black window and the graph is not displayed.
Suggestions on how to fix this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To get the snippet to run you have a small problem with you line

```
var edge_material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, linewidth: 2 } );
```

You can change this to:

```
var edge_material = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff,
  dashSize: 2,
  gapSize: 2
});
```

It should now render, but a black background still shows up. The problem now is that your camera is not angled at the content you have created, so add a line with a camera position below.

```
camera.position.y = 5;
```

Now you should be able to see your two boxes, and the line.

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x333333);

var node1_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var node1_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ff00
});
var node1 = new THREE.Mesh(node1_geometry, node1_material);
node1.position.set(-2, 4, 1);

var node2_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var node2_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xff00ff
});
var node2 = new THREE.Mesh(node2_geometry, node2_material);
node2.position.set(2, 4, 1);

var edge_geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
edge_geometry.vertices.push(node1.position, node2.position);
var edge_material = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff,
  dashSize: 2,
  gapSize: 2
});
var edge = new THREE.Line(edge_geometry, edge_material);

scene.add(node1);
scene.add(node2);
scene.add(edge);

camera.position.z = 5;
camera.position.y = 5;

var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.119.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great. Could you please suggest if there is an alternate way to do this? i.e. I don't want to change the camera position to be manually set everytime I create a new graph. Can we use an alternate function? For instance, if the position is changed `node1.position.set(-2, 4, 10)` I don't see the network on the html page again.

Comment: You can make the camera look at a object, or you could compute the center position for the camera to look at, and then position it manually. `camera.position.set(0, 9, 5);
camera.lookAt(node1.position);` This will make the camera look at `node1`

Comment: I tried this, but the node2 is hidden now

Comment: Yes, you positioned a node on each side of the camera, since the camera is positioned on the z axis on position 5 and node2 is on 1 and node1 is now positioned at 10, you now have a camera pointing at one of the two nodes. Making the other node hidden or out of sight. You need to figure out what you want to have in sight, and then calculate or otherwise position your camera to point at that. Move your camera to position 20 on the z-axis `camera.position.set(0, 5, 20);` and now the box is within the camera view again.